# Problem with the slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a slider(mainly border issues). You can see a slider [here](http://www2.learningrx.com/learningrx-franchise/)

Click on the **6. Owner** option and there you can see a border. This border should come on all the other tabs.

Comment: Please view the source and save this to an html file. Then all the code will be on your computer :)

Comment: As you can probably check and see with firebug the #slides div mask the content of the #menu div so the #menu background isn't visible unless you're viewing last slide (meaning there's nothing blocking the right end of the #menu background).

Comment: @WTK, don't understand. Can you elaborate more. FYI, i am not an designer(coder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution would be to wrap div #slides in yet another div with this css:

```
height: 231px;
left: 438px;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 185px;
width: 683px;
```

and from the declaration of ".tophdr_rt_slider #slides" remove two attributes:

```
float: left;
margin-top: -236px;
```

After that it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .slide {
      overflow:hidden;
  }
  .slide img {
      margin: 2px 10px 0px 10px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: ,. thanx for ur answer. It works but there is a problem, the border disappear(and comes again) when the slide rotates.

Comment: I don't see that problem. What browser are you using ?

Comment: my designer have resolved the issue. He has converted the all the images in slider into png(with transparent background)